# Problem implementing vertical swipe in Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, gesture, swipe

I asked a similar question in the android developers group but haven't received a response yet, so I figured I'd try my luck here.

I want to implement a vertical swipe on a Gallery and I have it working... sort of.  I subclassed Gallery so that I could override the onFling and onDown methods.

Here is the code I used to override these methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
{
    if (m_curTouchPos == NO_CURRENT_TOUCH_POS || m_callback == null)
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);

    float e1x = e1.getX();
    float e1y = e1.getY();
    float e2x = e2.getX();
    float e2y = e2.getY();

    float offPath = Math.abs(e1x - e2x);
    float distance = Math.abs(e1y - e2y);

    if (offPath < s_swipeMaxOffPath && 
        //Math.abs(velocityY) >= s_swipeMinVelocity && 
        distance >= s_swipeMinDistance)
    {
        if (e1y > e2y)
        {
            m_callback.onSwipeUp(m_curTouchPos);
            //return true;
        }
        else if (e2y > e1y)
        {
            //TODO: IMPLEMENT THIS
            //m_callback.onSwipeDown(m_curTouchPos);
            //return true;
        }
    }

    m_curTouchPos = NO_CURRENT_TOUCH_POS;
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent eve)
{
    m_curTouchPos = pointToPosition((int)eve.getX(), (int)eve.getY());
    return super.onDown(eve);
}
```

The problem is that onFling doesn't get called when I do a vertical swipe...  In order to get into the onFling method I have to press on an item in the gallery, slide it slowly a little to the left or right, and then swipe vertically.

Horizontal swipes always get into the onFling method.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the answer... The onDown() method needs to return true.  The call to return super.onDown(eve) was causing it to fail because the default implementation returns false.

I found the answer in another post here on StackOverflow:

[Android: GestureDetector not working (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) always false) with Tabs (TabActivity, Tabwidget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394025/android-gesturedetector-not-working-gesturedetector-ontoucheventevent-always)